# Collection.find().toArray returns an empty array Node.js MongoDB

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

Currently, I have a database that stores two collections, one for products and the other for orders for an e-commerce website. After starting up MongoDB, I loaded up data in the `mongo` shell. The following code is used to access the database via Collection.find() method.

```
var addOrder = function(db, order){
    var orders = db.collection('orders');
    var products = db.collection('products');

    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        if (orders) {
            console.log('orders');
            orders.find().toArray(function(err, docs) {
                console.log(docs);
            });         
        }

    })
}
```

Within the `mongo` shell, I can access both of them from the commands, `db.products.find()` and `db.orders.find()`. However the function above returns an empty array. I've replaced `orders` with `products` and I was able to obtain the data then. I can't seem to find a solution anywhere. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Check again the database name in  connection string of your node app.

Comment: in promise function you are checking `if(orders)` , do you mean its `order` rather than `orders`, addOrder function has parameter (db,order) and in promise you are checking for `orders`

Comment: and try to use `async-await` pattern. put `async at starting of function name and await keyword ahead of each time-consuming operation related to database query. in your case, it ` await  .toArray()` . async-await internally returns promise so better code structure you can find in your app